# Error 500 with php curl

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to do a curl that login in one website, the problem is that I keep getting Error 500--Internal Server Error.

Code:

```
<?php
$path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/teste/ctemp";

//login form action url 
$url="https://example/security_check"; 
$postinfo = "username=xxx&password=xxxx";
$website="https://example/account"; 
$base="https://example/"; 

$cookie_file_path = $path."/cookie.txt";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
//set the cookie the site has for certain features, this is optional
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "cookiename=0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postinfo);


curl_exec($ch);

//page with the content I want to grab
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $website);
//do stuff with the info with DomDocument() etc
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$html = preg_replace("/<head>/i", "<head><base href='$base' />", $html, 1); 

echo $html;
```

The website is https://example/, the auth form is submited to https://example/security_check with post username and password, after a sucessful login, the page is redirected to example/account 
Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Please, set a `var_dump('try 1') .... var_dump('try n') ` in each line and you will see where it's breaking. It's a practice faster. I hope help you.

Comment: The code works really well in another website that I tried, the problem is only with this one that Im trying to curl, I did some research and it appears that is because of cookies that are stored in login page and I'm calling the auth form direct via post, any tips for this ?

Comment: If you should send me complete code or send me link, I need testing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, reviewer your code, `$url` variable not exist:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

You should fix it.

Comment: Oh sorry for that, when I was editing the code, I changed the var name and forget to change in another line. But in original code the $urlform is $url, so still have the problem with 500 Internal Error